# Setting a variable outside the .jQuery.get() function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery.get() function get data from an url and set the retreived data to a variable outside this jQuery.get() function.

```
 var rating = 0;

 $.get( "/qwerty/res/film/rating?volgnummer=2", function( data ) {  // the url returns 99
     rating = data; 
      $( ".content" )
        .append(data); // returns 99 (as expected)
    }, "json" );

alert(rating); // returns 0 (99 expected)
```

The .append(data) returns the right result but when I alert the rating variable outside the get function it returns 0(which should be 99)

Why isn't the rating variable set to 99(from data)?

Comment: This is because all AJAX callas are asynchonous. Your `alert()` is being executed before the AJAX call is completed.

Comment: Also, the first person who suggests making the call synchronous gets a slap.

Comment: This question has been asked a lot of times before have a look at the link from RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Because `ajax` is *asynchronous*. Your `alert` runs *before* the `ajax` callback that sets `rating`.

---

*(CW because this is **such** a duplicate!)*

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `alert` is called before `$.get` finished execution.

try this:

```
var rating = 0;
get_json(function(){
    alert(rating);
});
function get_json(callback){
    $.get( "/qwerty/res/film/rating?volgnummer=2", function( data ) {  // the url returns 99
        rating = data; 
        $( ".content" ).append(data); // returns 99 (as expected)
    }, "json" );
}
```